# PHP 7 - SFTP keeps interrupting page to load

Tags: php, sftp

I'm currently trying to get a file from a server by php sftp. I managed to authenticate and connect to the server. The problem is, that if I want to open a dir on said server, the page just keeps loading until my browser tells me the loading of the page has been interrupted. This only happens, if I try open a dir that EXISTS. If I open a dir that doesn't exist, I get a normal error message.
Therefor I'm not quite sure, wether this is a mistake in my code or a problem with the ftp server.

My Code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

$host = "<host>";
$port = 22;
$conn = ssh2_connect($host);
$username = "<user>";
$pub_key = "/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub";
$pri_key = "/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa";
if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(
    $conn,
    $username,
    $pub_key,
    $pri_key
)) {
    if(!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn)){
        die("SFTP Connection failed");
    };
    opendir("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."/./");
};
```

Has anyone ever experienced something similar?
I'd be glad for any help :)

~François

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the expected way.

`Opendir` return a handle. Your function is working, it's just that you do nothing with the data, and your php script do nothing. It's just waiting with the information
Just handle data, or at least write an `echo` and it should be ok.

check the manual, there is a working example http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Comment: Uhh thank you... I'm sorry i even checked the docs, but somehow missed that. Well thank you! I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I can (stackoverflow has set a time limit there).

Comment: You're welcome ! We all have done some mistakes where we forget to write one line.